# Use a query as an entity attribute in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, annotations

I've got an entity with a field declared as :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="xxxx")
private List<MyObject> myObjects;
```

I would like to add an attribute that would be a single element of that list. Is it possible to do that directly with annotations ?

Something like :

```
@Query("FROM XXXX WHERE effectivityDate=currentDate")
private MyObject mySpecificObject;
```

Is that possible or should I have to create a classic DAO query ?

Thanks

Comment: I went with the NamedQuery and a DAO, but I'm still interested on this.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do that? You have that information on the List (but it would be better using a Set). You can use the Open-session-in-view pattern to access to *mySpecificObject* properties from view layer (or create a MySpecificObjectDetails class and save that information for each mySpecificObject on a Set).

Comment: The MyObject objetcs have a timestamp which can be in the past and in the future. The specific object I want to retrieve is the one effective at the current date. I could use a NamedQuery and a DAO but I was wondering if it could be done like this.